# How to show image in a GridView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-gridview

I developed an app, in which the user can change the background. I have successfully changed it.

The only problem is that when the user clicks on the preference screen to change background it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/suiRq.png but I want it to show in GridView as Gallery.

My Preference Activity code:

```
private static final int[] ChHAT_IMG = new int[]{R.drawable.wallpaper_1,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_2,R.drawable.wallpaper_3
       ,R.drawable.wallpaper_4,
        R.drawable.black_floral_leaf_pattern,
        R.drawable.niggt,R.drawable.sky_at_night,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_5,R.drawable.wallpaper_6
        ,R.drawable.wallpaper_7,
        R.drawable.wallpaper_9,R.drawable.wallpaper_10
        ,R.drawable.wallpaper_11,R.drawable.wallpaper_12
        ,R.drawable.wallpaper_13,R.drawable.wallpaper_16,R.drawable.wallpaper_17,R.drawable.wallpaper_20,R.drawable.wallpaper_21,

        };

/**
 * String resources for wallpaer.
 */
private static final int[] CHAT_STR = new int[]{
        R.string.wallpaper1, R.string.wallpaper2, R.string.wallpaper3, R.string.wallpaper4,
        R.string.wallpaper5, R.string.wallpaper6, R.string.wallpaper7, R.string.wallpaper8,
        R.string.wallpaper9, R.string.wallpaper10, R.string.wallpaper11, R.string.wallpaper12,R.string.wallpaper13,R.string.wallpaper14,
R.string.wallpaper15,   R.string.wallpaper16,   R.string.wallpaper17,   R.string.wallpaper18,
        R.string.wallpaper19, };

private static class OnWallpaperClickListener implements
        Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
    private final Context ctx;
    public OnWallpaperClickListener(final Context context) {
        ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {

        final Builder b = new Builder(ctx);
        final int l = CHAT_STR.length;
        final String[] cols = new String[]{"icon", "text"};
        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> rows
                = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            final HashMap<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>(2);
            m.put(cols[0], ChHAT_IMG[i]);
            m.put(cols[1], ctx.getString(CHAT_STR[i]));
            rows.add(m);
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.grid, null );
        SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(ctx, rows, R.layout.wallpaper_icons_item, cols,
                        new int[]{android.R.id.icon, android.R.id.text1});
        GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        // Setting an adapter containing images to the gridview
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //   b.setView(gridView);
        AlertDialog dialog=b.create();
        b.setAdapter(adapter,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, final int which) {
                        preference.getEditor().putInt(preference.getKey(), which).commit();
                    }
                });
        b.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null);
        b.show();
        return true;
    }
}
```

**pref_apperance.xml**

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="chat"
    android:summary="Set wallpaper for message"</PreferenceScreen>"
```

**grid.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1">
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    />
```

**wallpaper_icons_item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
<ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/R.drawable.wallpaper_4"/>
      <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="android:id/text1"/></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

create a `CoustomAdapter` for your `gridview` and set the value like below code

**code is =>**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

String [] result;
Context context;
  int [] imageId;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] textList, int[] Imagestext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=textList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=Imageslist;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;

         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
         holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

     holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
     holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

     rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    return rowView;
    }

 }
```

and set the adapter in main activity like

```
 gv=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);      
    gv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, textList,Imageslist));
```

may be help you